# como ofuscar codigo js

Tags: javascript, html, app, ofuscación

quiero saber si existe alguna forma de ofuscar código javascript de la manera más compleja posible para evitar que sea fácil de adquirir y modificar. **QUE SEA 100% OFFLINE Y GRATIS**. Ya he visto otras apps como JavaScriptObfuscator.exe (muy buena por cierto) pero lo que no me gusta de ella es que necesito conexión a internet, en fin, si es posible que me recomienden un ofuscador de código js, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `javascript-obfuscator` aqui te dejo el enlace del proyecto en [GitHub](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator), la instalación y uso es sencilla:

```
yarn add --dev javascript-obfuscator
```

o

```
npm install --save-dev javascript-obfuscator
```

Uso:

```
var JavaScriptObfuscator = require('javascript-obfuscator');

var obfuscationResult = JavaScriptObfuscator.obfuscate(
    `
        (function(){
            var variable1 = '5' - 3;
            var variable2 = '5' + 3;
            var variable3 = '5' + - '2';
            var variable4 = ['10','10','10','10','10'].map(parseInt);
            var variable5 = 'foo ' + 1 + 1;
            console.log(variable1);
            console.log(variable2);
            console.log(variable3);
            console.log(variable4);
            console.log(variable5);
        })();
    `,
    {
        compact: false,
        controlFlowFlattening: true,
        controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 1,
        numbersToExpressions: true,
        simplify: true,
        stringArrayShuffle: true,
        splitStrings: true,
        stringArrayThreshold: 1
    }
);

console.log(obfuscationResult.getObfuscatedCode());
```